# index.js:1335 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor).

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a problem after adding `react-ladda` plugin.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import LaddaButton, { EXPAND_RIGHT } from 'react-ladda';
import { signinUser } from '../../actions/AuthActions';

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { loading: false };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.email).focus();
    }

    handleFormSubmit({ username, password }) {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        this.props.signinUser({ username, password });
    }

    renderAlert() {
        this.setState({ loading: false });

        if (this.props.errorMessage) {
            const message = this.props.errorMessage;
            return (
                <div className="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>{message.title}</strong>
                    <ul>
                        <li>{message.message}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="account-pages login-pages" />
                <div className="clearfix" />
                <div className="wrapper-page">

                    <div className="m-t-40 card-box">
                        <div className="text-center">
                            <h4 className="text-uppercase font-bold m-b-0">Sign In</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="panel-body">
                            {this.renderAlert()}

                            <form
                                className="form-horizontal m-t-20" name="form"
                                onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}
                                >
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <Field
                                        className="form-control input-lg" component="input"
                                        type="text" name="email" ref="email" placeholder="email"
                                        />
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <Field
                                        className="form-control input-lg" component="input" type="password"
                                        name="password" placeholder="password"
                                        />
                                </div>

                                <div className="form-group text-center m-t-20">
                                    <LaddaButton
                                        action="submit"
                                        loading={this.state.loading}
                                        data-style={EXPAND_RIGHT}
                                        className="btn btn-custom btn-bordred btn-block waves-effect waves-light"
                                        >
                                        SIGN IN
                                </LaddaButton>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        errorMessage: state.auth.error
    };
}

Login = reduxForm({
    form: 'loginForm',
})(Login);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { signinUser })(Login);
```

When I run it my console show `index.js:1335 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`or another component's constructor).` and the app is crash.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting state in `renderAlert` and then use it in `render`. You should not set state in `render` method. I'm not sure about your logic, but `isLoading` is `false`, you are changing it when user submit a form. Doesnt make sense to change it to `true` once page is rendered (that's from another view)

Comment: hi. I'm still new at react. I want to achieve, when every time user click the button it will trigger Ladda, after it finish change the state back to normal either it success or fail. So where should I set the state to false after it change?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, you cannot change state inside render, because that causes a re-render, which will change state again...then you will have an endless loop. :(

If you want to set a loading variable and want to update the variable once you receive new props, you could use `componentDidUpdate()`, then you can check that a certain thing succeeded, and toggle the variable.

For instance, say that you wanted to check if you got a new error, then you could set the loading variable in there, or you could just check if the loading variable was true on update, and then set it to false.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // if the component has updated and loading is still set to true, set it to false    
    if (this.state.loading) {
        this.setState({ loading: false })
    }

    // or if you want to check if the error prop has changed and reset loading
    if (this.props.errorMessage !== prevProps.errorMessage) {
        this.setState({ loading: false })
    }
}
```

read more about `componentDidUpdate` (and other React Lifecycle methods) [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. I tried your way, but I got an error `Do not use setState in componentDidUpdate`, and when I ran the app is crash.

Comment: You need to use componentDidUpdate not componentWillUpdate

Comment: sorry i mean `componentDidUpdate`. hehe. I've tried both will and did the app is crashing

Comment: I think there may be something else going on, because I've set state inside componentDidUpdate in many different components.